# Calculate SIFT features at specific image positions

Tags: image-processing

Is it possible to use ImageKeypoints[...] to calculate SIFT feature vectors at specific image coordinates?

Comment: `ImageKeypoints[]` uses SURF transform, which is often superior to SIFT.  But I think you would need to code up your own SIFT feature transform.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate SURF features at specific grid positions? I need this for feature extraction on texture image patches.

Comment: A simple hack would be to extract the small patch of the image centered on the point in question, then apply `ImageKeypoints[]` with a threshold that returned a very large number of features, and choose the returned feature closest to the center.